# MSVC's stdlib and fma() function template

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am writing a mathematical library which provides an FMA (fused multiply-add) primitive for one of my user-defined types (called `real`). The prototype of the function looks something like:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename V, Enabler<T,U,V> = 0>
real fma(T &&x, U &&y, V &&z);
```

The `Enabler<T,U,V>` bit is a SFINAE construction that removes the `fma()` function from the overload set if `T`, `U` and `V` are not all of type `real` (after the removal of cv qualifications and reference qualifiers). I am using templates and forwarding references in order to provide the possibility to pilfer resources from one of the function arguments when constructing the return value of the function.

My `fma()` function is intended to be used via argument-dependent lookup, and it works fine in GCC and clang (both using libstdc++ and libc++). MSVC however errors out:

https://ci.appveyor.com/project/bluescarni/mppp/build/557/job/m25u5g59tp49jfl3#L1049

The problem seems to be the presence of a function template `fma()` defined in the root namespace:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h(146): note: or       'float fma<mppp::real,mppp::real,mppp::real>(_Ty1,_Ty2,_Ty3)'
      with
      [
          _Ty1=mppp::real,
          _Ty2=mppp::real,
          _Ty3=mppp::real
      ]
C:\projects\mppp\test\real_basic.cpp(48): note: while trying to match the argument list '(mppp::real, mppp::real, mppp::real)'
```

As far as I have understood, C specifies the presence of various floating-point overloads for the `fma()` function, and C++ has more overloads available as `std::fma()`. According to this page,

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fma

C++ might also provide a function template overload when the arguments are of arithmetic types. MSVC however does not constrain its `fma()` template to arithmetic types, rather it gobbles up any argument type.

My question is then: is this a valid behaviour from MSVC?

**EDIT**: I have added a minimal example here:

<del>http://rextester.com/IAG22173</del>

http://rextester.com/MFL21299

Comment: Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is not really possible to tell.

Comment: @VTT added a minimal example.